# How to make a GitHub Actions workflow page publicly visible

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions

I have set up a GitHub Actions workflow for my project and want users to check the current workflow status. I added a badge that links to the workflow page, in that form:

`https://github.com/<user>/<repo>/actions?query=workflow%3A<workflow>`

When I sign out of GitHub, the badge still works, but the link points to an 404 error page. I have seen this in other users repositories as well.

Is there any way to make the GitHub Action pages publicly visible?

Comment: I don't think it is possible currently to do this. The `Actions` tab is not even visible unless one is logged in, so I doubt the actual actions will be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just checked, and the Actions workflow pages seem to be publicly accessible by default now, via the badge as described above.

The `Actions` tab as well as the indicator next to the latest commit are also visible now, even if signed out.